# Is it okay to say "There´s a picture on the fireplace" as equivalent to "There´s a picture on the mantelpiece?

Tags: word-usage

Is it okay to say "There´s a picture on the fireplace" as equivalent to  "There´s a picture on the mantelpiece?

Comment: With no other context, I'd assume that you meant sitting at the base of the chimney, on the surround of the hearth itself rather than on the mantelpiece

Comment: There is a picture *above* the fireplace.